# Adding a background color hides my line

Tags: ios, colors

I have created a line using UIBezier Path:

```
    UIBezierPath *path2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(110, 290)];
    [path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(310, 290)];
    path2.lineWidth = 1;
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [path2 stroke];
```

But when I added this:

```
 UIColor *color4 = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.98 green:0.91 blue:0.71 alpha:1];
 self.view.backgroundColor = color4;
```

I was not able to see the line again. Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: what is contentView ?

Comment: Are you trying to add it to the tableview cell's content view ?

Comment: contentView is a UIView, sorry I will change it in the question to make it more clear